# Olympiad inequality $\frac{a}{c+5b}+\frac{b}{a+5c}+\frac{c}{b+5a}\geq \frac{1}{2}$ for all positive $a,b,c$?

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

How can I prove that $\frac{a}{c+5b}+\frac{b}{a+5c}+\frac{c}{b+5a}\geq \frac{1}{2}$ for all positive $a,b,c$?

Comment: what about your attempt regarding this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Use Cauchy-Schwarz Angel form and write $\dfrac{a}{c+5b} = \dfrac{a^2}{ac+5ab}$. Do this for each term. After the first application of the CS inequality, then use the CS inequality once more but in the form $(a+b+c)^2 \ge 3(ab+bc+ca)$ to conclude. Can you write it down all the details?

Answer (score 0):

Just for the trial, try to prove that:
$$\dfrac{a}{xb+yc}+\dfrac{b}{xc+ya}+\dfrac{c}{xa+yb} \geq \dfrac{3}{x+y}.$$

It's an expansion of the one you have asked for and other Nesbitt-similar inequality.